# Existence of a solution to a congruence

Tags: number-theory

I need to check if congruence
$$x^2+8x+69\equiv 0\pmod{271},$$
has a solution. How should I approach this? Checking all $271$ possible solutions, is obviously not intended.

Comment: [This](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCQQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.science.mq.edu.au%2F~chris%2Fnumbers%2FCHAP03%2520Quadratic%2520Congruences.pdf&ei=PMpZVcnTHMSLuATvsYK4Cw&usg=AFQjCNG_SrXtcVSFmYRqjfgG5jkAf4Tsmw&sig2=zAuZAIQ0Q-FDODh7YapChQ&bvm=bv.93564037,d.c2E&cad=rja) might help.

Comment: The congruence in the question is the same as $(x+4)^2\equiv 218\pmod{271}$. Next, you just use the techniques used for solving quadratic congruences. Refer to that pdf link I gave. It might help to note that $271$ is a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadratic's discriminant is

$$8^2-4\cdot69=-212=59\pmod{271}$$

Now use the Quadratic Reciprocity to find out whether $\;59\;$ is a square modulo $\;271\;$ :

$$\binom{59}{271}=-\binom{35}{59}=-\binom5{59}\binom7{59}=\binom45\binom37=-1\binom13=-1$$

so the quadratic is irreducible modulo $\;271\;$  and thus it has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Proceed as you would in the reals; that is use the formula you know for solving quadratics.

As in the reals, it might happen the discriminant has no square root, then you have no solutions.

If you just want to know if there are solutions it will suffice to check if the discriminant has a root (is a quadratic residue) or not.